# How To Passing Parameters to Data Factory Activities

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created two parameters at the pipeline level. There are 3 activities in a pipeline to which I want to send these parameters.
The parameter for activity is the file path and that is getting created based on the pipeline level parameters. I have used below code to form a path but getting an error - invalid  - 'concat' does not have an overload that supports the arguments given

`@concat('weather/data/',adddays(utcnow(),pipeline().parameters.numdays,'yyyy'),'/',adddays(utcnow(),pipeline().parameters.numdays,'MM'),'/',adddays(utcnow(),pipeline().parameters.numdays,'dd'),'.IND.',pipeline().parameters.instance,'.csv')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can it be that one of the arguments isn't a string, e.g. pipeline().parameters.instance? Maybe you need to convert it into a string.

Comment: Perfect!! yes, the type of the parameter was Int which was causing the issue. I changed the parameter type and it worked. Thanks!!!